# tcpdump / wireshark capturing problems

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

just started with wireshark and tcpdump,
they both work fine if I capture traffic on my IP but doesn`t capture anything on other sources (other IP on my network)

my setup : 1 pc running windows 8(ip 192.168.0.2), 1 laptop running ubuntu(192.168.0.3).

Both connected to a cheap unmanaged 5 port switch , that is connected to my router.

Both wired, even tried with the laptop on wireless mode.

if I run tcpdump on my laptop with filters: host 192.168.0.2(computer IP add) it does not capture anything!

Same if I run wireshark on my computer but use filters such as dest 192.168.0.3 (laptops IP)

Tried tcpdump with net 192.168.0.0/24 (should be capturing traffic from my whole network)... same result , captures only traffic that is destined to my IP (laptop from witch I am runing the command)

Tried setting to Promiscuous ON , on both the laptop and pc , same result.

Any ideea why I am not being able to capture anything from other IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Both connected to a cheap unmanaged 5 port switch"*

As you've already discovered, your current capture setup won't work.  From the Wireshark [CaptureSetup/Ethernet](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) wiki page:

> In addition, if you are on a switched Ethernet, rather than a shared
>   Ethernet, you will also have to take action to ensure that all traffic
>   in which you're interested is sent to the Ethernet adapter on the
>   machine running the packet capture program; that is not, by default,
>   the case on switched networks, so attempts to capture on a switched
>   network will, by default, see only traffic that the capturing machine
>   would see when not in promiscuous mode.

Refer to that same page for a number of solutions, including using a TAP, a managed switch, or even a hub (if you can even find one and have no other choice), just to name a few.

In addition to the Wireshark wiki page, I'd also highly recommend reading the very talented Jasper Bongertz's 6-part ***Network Capture Playbook*** series:

1. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 1 – Ethernet Basics](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/10/the-network-capture-playbook-part-1-ethernet-basics/)
2. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 2 – Speed, Duplex and Drops](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/10/the-network-capture-playbook-part-2-speed-duplex-and-drops/)
3. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 3 – Network cards](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/11/the-network-capture-playbook-part-3-network-cards/)
4. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 4 – SPAN Port In-Depth](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/11/the-network-capture-playbook-part-4-span-port-in-depth/)
5. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 5 – Network TAP Basics](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/12/the-network-capture-playbook-part-5-network-tap-basics/)
6. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 6 – Planning Network Troubleshooting](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2018/01/the-network-capture-playbook-part-6-planning-network-troubleshooting/)